# Time required for DNA replication in E. coli

Tags: molecular-genetics, homework, dna-replication

In a particular strain of *E. coli*, it was observed that DNA polymerase could add nucleotides to a growing chain of DNA at the rate of 600 per second. If the genome of this organism is 1.1mm long wherein a base pair occupies 0.34 nm, then how much time (in minutes) would be required for the complete replication of the chromosomal DNA molecule?
(Report the closest integer value.) {[Source](https://olympiads.hbcse.tifr.res.in/olympiads/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/inbo2014-Q.pdf)}

I solved this question using this method.

No. of base pairs: $ \frac{1.1  \times 10^{-3} \space m}{0.34 \times 10^{-9} \space m/bp} = 3.23 \times 10^{6} \space bp$

Time required for replication (in minutes by the DNA Polymerase) = $ \frac{ 3.23 \times 10^{6} \space bp}{(600 \space bp/s)\times (60 \space s/minute)} =89.86 ≈ 90 \space minutes$

The answer, however, is 45 minutes. What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that *E. coli* has a single circular chromosome, and that chromosome is replicated bidirectionally. Hence, your calculated value (90 minutes) is exactly twice that of the correct answer.